# Array with double parameters

Tags: c++, arrays

I am reading some book and I have encountered a piece of code that wasn't explained in the book, but has some part which is very confusing to me, bold part, and I want to know what is it about.

```
void Set::intersection(const Set& s1, const Set& s2)
{
    Set s;
    s.arrayA = new double[ s1.sizeA<s2.sizeA ? s1.sizeA : s2.sizeA];
    int i, j, k;
    while(i < s1.sizeA && j < s2.sizeA)
        if(s1.arrayA[i] < s2.arrayA[j])
            i++;
        else if (s1.arrayA[i] > s2.arrayA[j])
            j++;
        else
            s.arrayA[k++] = s1.arrayA[j++,i++]; // question is about this line

    s.sizeA= k;
    deleteA();
    copyA(s);  
}
```

What does it do, and why is there two parameters inside the [] brackets? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really got this from a book?? This looks dodgy -- s.sizeA= k; but k is not initialised, unless you have omitted something.

Comment: Look 5th line. @mathematician1975

Comment: So what is the value of k then?

Comment: If this book is your school homework task book, please add tag "homework".

Comment: @Takarakaka : The 5th line _declares_ `k`, but does not _initialize_ it.

Comment: Done! @Ruben ~Mathematician You were right, I mistyped it, now it's fixed. Look at the 12th line.

Comment: `i`, `j` and `k` are still not initialised with any values before they are used!

Comment: `s.arrayA[i++] = s1.arrayA[j++,i++];` -- that looks like UB to me. The comma operator introduces a sequence point, but because `operator=` is not a sequence point, the compiler is still free to compute where the RHS value is be stored either before or after it computes the RHS value. I think. In any case, it's *dodgy*.

Comment: @DavidHammen Hm? I don't see that code anywhere in the OP's example.

Comment: @Takarakaka UB = Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @MrLister: That was a copy and paste. You can still see the original code in the accepted answer. Apparently the OP changed the code between when I did the copy and the paste. In between I double checked that it was undefined behavior. I did not check to see if the code had been changed.

Comment: @DavidHammen I see now, sorry. But don't worry, there's still undefined behaviour in the program with the uninitialised variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parameter within brackets is expression using [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). Result of such expression is result of last item (`j++, i++` gives i incremented by one, while j is also incremented by one).
So `s.arrayA[i++] = s1.arrayA[j++,i++];` really can be converted to equal `j++, s.arrayA[i++] = s1.arrayA[i++];`

This code [intersects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) to sets `s1` and `s2`. It seems code suggests that arrays (that implement sets) are sorted.
Code is walking on `s1.arrayA` and `s2.arrayA` and if some element is present in both sets, than it places that element in `s.arrayA`.

Comment: OK, but how is it possible to do such a thing? It's not clear to me? What constructor is called? And why first j++ and only later i++?

Comment: It seems that `Set s;` calls default constructor for `Set`.

Comment: Aha, it is so much clear to me now. So why would I discard my first operator at all?

Comment: You cannot discard that operator, because it defines variable you use later. So is this code yours or from some book?)

Comment: From a book written by our local programmer.